# Where did the Fables get all those weapons in the first place?

Tags: comics, fables-comic, bill-willingham

In the second volume of *Fables*, *Animal Farm*, we see that the Fables possess an enormous amount of various firearms:

[image]

Where did they come from? Snow White states in the first volume that Fables are on a tight budget. She also states most of them couldn't save their wealths from Fable Land when they ran away.

Even past that, had they had those they'd use them to fight the adversary. This all leads me to believe the Animal Farm acquired those weapons after they escaped, and did so in secret, so that the Fabletown didn't know.

Is it ever explained, maybe in the future volumes (I'm only on volume II), where they got the weapons from?

Answer (score 2):

While it is never really stated straight, we can speculate:

1. Fables are in constant threat - weapons are important to them.

   Fables are very afraid - they are refugees from the Adversary's war machine, that has conquered countless kingdoms. Earth is their stand (not necessarily final - there were places that Adversary haven't conquered, like the Cloud kingdom of giants or the SF worlds), but they don't want to run anymore - hence they try to arm themselves with modern weapons. Also, those are Fabletown owned weapons - they have been bought with "state" money - and while indeed Fabletown is not particulars rich <sup>*</sup>, it still can afford to buy few guns here and there.
2. They've been here for a while

   Fables moved to our Earth [quite a while ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104264/when-did-the-fables-move-to-our-world) (they've been here at very least since 1664) - that would give them time to start working on their armaments.
3. They have a genius blacksmith(s)

   They have quite a lots of skilled people who can make weapons -  [Weyland Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_the_Smith) comes to mind here.
4. Other methods

   They have fables that can fly, go invisible, teleport - it really wouldn't be that difficult to steal some stuff, if not from military bases, then from private owners, criminals etc.

<sup>Weeeeellll... kind of... Bluebeard had full rooms full of gold and Frau Totenkinder at one stage created a purse that was pouring gold out of it, so saying "poor" is relative</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I read through Fables, but while Vol 1 is set in Fabletown proper, which as Snow says may have to operate on a tight budget, while Vol 2 takes place on the Farm, a separate administrative area for non-human Fables, such as talking animals. SPOILER for Vol 2 if you haven't read it, but the Farm Fables have held Weyland Smith, a blacksmith Fable based on the Germanic Wayland the Smith, and either threatened or bewitched him to craft weapons for them, ostensibly for the rebellion against Fabletown depicted in Vol 2. If you're asking where they got the materials for such an arsenal to be created, I guess that's never really acknowledged, but I'm sure there's some reference made to the Farm subsiding off the sellable products such as milk, wool, eggs etc of the animal residents, not 100% sue on that, though.

Comment: Add to that, how *long* the farm exists already, they had plenty time.